Change main page not working android studio

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.parrot.camera.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:exported="true">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.parrot.camera.BatteryStatusActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

    droneBatteryInfo = findViewById(R.id.droneBatteryTxt)
    remoteBatteryInfo = findViewById(R.id.remoteBatteryTxt)
   
    val flyViewBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.connectDroneBtn)
    flyViewBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent (this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    updateBatteryStatus()

}

I try to change many ways but still not working. Can anyone help me??
My android studio app original main page is mainActivity, but I want to change to other activity, call BatteryStatusActivity.
I change the AndroidManifest.xml file as below. And after this change, it always show me error as
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.parrot.camera, PID: 28232
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parrot.camera/com.parrot.camera.BatteryStatusActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c001c

post your BatteryStatusActivity code

Why your manifest.xml have kotlin code inside it?
Please post files separately.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

package com.parrot.camera
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.parrot.drone.groundsdk.GroundSdk
import com.parrot.drone.groundsdk.ManagedGroundSdk
import com.parrot.drone.groundsdk.device.instrument.BatteryInfo
import com.parrot.drone.groundsdk.facility.AutoConnection
import java.time.Instant

class BatteryStatusActivity :AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var droneBatteryInfo: TextView
    private lateinit var remoteBatteryInfo: TextView
    //follow the main to add groundsdk to get sdk
    private lateinit var groundSdk: GroundSdk


    override fun onCreate(saveInstanceState: Bundle?)  {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery_status)
        // Initialize GroundSdk
        groundSdk = ManagedGroundSdk.obtainSession(this)

        droneBatteryInfo = findViewById(R.id.droneBatteryTxt)
        remoteBatteryInfo = findViewById(R.id.remoteBatteryTxt)
        // link to main fly model (id is connect to drone)
        val flyViewBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.connectDroneBtn)
        flyViewBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent (this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)}
        updateBatteryStatus()
    }

    private fun updateBatteryStatus()  {
        groundSdk = ManagedGroundSdk.obtainSession(this)
        //auto connect
        val autoConnection = groundSdk.getFacility(AutoConnection::class.java)
        autoConnection?.let {facility->
            facility.start()
            // Subscribe to drone's battery information
            facility.drone?.getInstrument(BatteryInfo::class.java) { batteryInfo ->
                batteryInfo?.let { info ->
                    droneBatteryInfo.text = "Drone Battery: ${info.charge}%"
                } ?: run {
                    droneBatteryInfo.text = "Drone Battery: --%"
                }
            }
           facility.remoteControl?.let {
               Log.d("BatteryStatus", "Remote control is connected")
               it.getInstrument(BatteryInfo::class.java) {batteryInfo ->
                   batteryInfo?.let { info ->
                       remoteBatteryInfo.text ="Remote Battery: ${info.charge}%"
                   }?:run {
                       remoteBatteryInfo.text = "Remote Battery: --%"
                   }

               }
           }

        }

    }
}


This is my BatteryStatusActivity code for reference

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parrot.camera">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.parrot.camera.BatteryStatusActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.parrot.camera.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:exported="false">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


Hi, thank you so much for helping. I may accidently added onCreate after manifest. I will post my BatteryStatusActivity code after this
